# Loss-free resistor model

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, modeling, power-factor-correction

Can someone use a simple explanation to tell me what a loss-free resistor model is? I googled it but it is hard to understand. When I study power factor correction circuits, I see some [papers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270793300_Bridgeless_PFC_Modified_SEPIC_Rectifier_with_Extended_Gain_for_Universal_Input_Voltage_Applications) use this model to analyze it.

[image]

There are my questions:

1. What is the loss-free resistor model?
2. Why do we need to use this model to model the PFC?
3. A resistor will cause a power loss, why is it called a loss-free resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *loss-free resistor* or LFR is a concept which lets you model a lossless energy transfer between a source and a receptor. This model is featuring a resistance which models the energy absorption and a current source which models the lossless transfer to a load. This is called *loss-free* because all the power absorbed by the resistor is transmitted to the load. The model is shown below:

[image]

It has been popularized by Bob Erickson and Dragan Maksimovic in their book *Fundamentals of Power Electronics* to model discontinuous-mode-operated power converters.

To model a PFC output power stage, you can resort to this model as the input resistance is emulated by the control law and 100% of the absorbed power goes to the output. I personally prefer to implement a simpler approach where you write a large-signal equation describing how the power is transmitted to the load. This current depends on the adopted control law (how the duty ratio or \$t_{on}\$ is generated) and you linearize the source to obtain a small-signal model:

[image]

This picture is excerpted from my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1949267512) on transfer functions. It illustrates a simplified means to model a PFC and determine its control-to-output transfer function.

Comment: Thank you. very useful

Comment: How do different active PFC ccts react to square wave inverter sources?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a switch-mode circuit to make sure V = I * K, where V is source voltage, I is load current and K is a constant (or slowly changing parameter) then you have created something that LOOKS LIKE a resistor to the voltage source. This has a favorable power factor from the perspective of the utility power.

A control loop can vary K at a frequency far from 50 or 60 Hz, and practically speaking, this does not harm power factor.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What the picture is indicating is this: -

1. Power factor correction relies on making a load look like a linear resistor
2. The "final" load is a capacitor in parallel with RL.
3. That load is not linear (due to other unmentioned components such as a bridge rectifier for instance) and together, they exhibit a poor power factor.
4. Hence, the power taken by resistor Re is regarded as the "aim" of the circuit
5. So, the power taken by Re is projected onto Co and RL

From this point, an analysis of the Re power waveform applied to Co and RL is done.

Having said all of that, I think the term "loss-free resistor" is a little too far-fetched in summarising what Re actually is and what it represents. OK it works in conjunction with Pac and it can be argued that all the thermal heat generated by Re is re-converted back to the equivalent electrical power generated by Pac for feeding Co and RL.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of active PFC is make the current phase track the Voltage amplitude of the incoming line by switching the duty cycle of the inductor of some values (d.f. * fs = On time ) but the amplitude scaled by the real part of the load current.

- thus with dI/dt = V(t)/L dt is regulated to make the I amplitude follow the load R and the phase due to C is compensated.
- With a small C, start surge current can be reduced significantly at high fs rates.
- the resulting Vdc must only be 10 to 20% above the Vpk of the incoming signal.
- The net result is Re in series is near zero or <5% of the minimum load R for the Ron of the FET and choice of DCR for the L. But “Re in shunt”  might be the conjugate of C(ac-f) to null it’s effect in parallel by active tracking of phase by switched time loading of L thus make Re look like the linear load as the total load.
- For active PFC to work efficiently with an inverter output as in a UPS network solution, the inverter output must be a sine wave output rather than a tri-level square wave , so that UPS loads also with active PFC front ends can operate efficiently tracking the input voltage curve thereby improving overall efficiency greatly.

  - take note: UPS with non sine outputs cannot meet their rated P output with loads that use active PFC.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that XL =2\$\pi\$L means a passive PFC at 50 Hz requires a much smaller L when scaled by active PFC scaled by f